# Changing views from Libgdx in Android dynamically

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I have two separate 3D Libgdx projects, let's call them **SceneOne** and **SceneTwo**.
Let's say I have a layout in Android in which I have two buttons: ButtonA and ButtonB.
When I click **ButtonA** **SceneOne** is visible in the layout, when I click **ButtonB** **SceneTwo** shows up and replaces **SceneOne**. They switch with each other.

Here's pseudo-code that works but initializes the views every time which results in poor performance:

```
View SceneOne;
View SceneTwo;

void onButtonAClick()
{
this.removeView(SceneTwo);
RendererA renderer = new Renderer(); // my Libgdx class implementing ApplicationListener
SceneOne = ((AndroidApplication)context).initializeForView(renderer, cfg);
addView(SceneOne);
}


void onButtonBClick()
{
this.removeView(SceneOne);
RendererB renderer = new Renderer(); 
SceneTwo = ((AndroidApplication)context).initializeForView(renderer, cfg);
addView(SceneTwo);
}
```

It's slow but it works. But it stops working when I change the initialization to lazy like this

```
View SceneOne;
View SceneTwo;

void onButtonAClick()
{
this.removeView(SceneTwo);
if ( SceneOne == null)
{
RendererA renderer = new Renderer(); // my Libgdx class implementing ApplicationListener
SceneOne = ((AndroidApplication)context).initializeForView(renderer, cfg);
}
addView(SceneOne);
}


void onButtonBClick()
{
this.removeView(SceneOne);
if ( SceneTwo == null)
{
RendererB renderer = new Renderer(); 
SceneTwo = ((AndroidApplication)context).initializeForView(renderer, cfg);
}
addView(SceneTwo);
}
```

What happens is:

1. **SceneOne** shows up.
2. I click **ButtonB**
3. **SceneTwo** shows up
4. I click **ButtonA**
5. Something weird shows up on the screen, it looks like **SceneTwo** but with some artifacts.
6. When i try to switch the same artifact scene stays on the screen.

Why does this happen and how should I fix it ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a new class named `AndroidFragmentApplication` and just switched fragments while keeping refrences to them, hence with no need to re-initialize it every time I switch.